# How to update a record in database based on a variable in Python?

Tags: python

How can I update a record in a database based on a variable?

I have a variable named `run_time_start` that is previously sent to the database.

But then, at some point, I want to update 2 columns in the same record, with the values of the variables `end_date` and `total_time`

is there any way I can do something like this?

```
engine.execute("UPDATE control_general_log SET (end_date, total_time) VALUES (?, ?)", run_time_end, total_elapsed_time, "WHERE chain_script = ?", run_time_start)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
engine.execute("UPDATE control_general_log SET end_date=?, total_time=? WHERE chain_script = ?", (run_time_end, total_elapsed_time, run_time_start,)

conn.commit()  # conn is your connection variable
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It didn't raise any error but it also didn't write to the db

Comment: make sure u use commit(), i dont know how u call to your connection object ( the one u use to generete the "engine" cursor)